# Он уволен "из студии" или "со студии"?

Tags: предлоги

Он был уволен **из студии** или **со студии**? Как правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я начала вот отсюда. Работал (где?):

[СТУ́ДИЯ](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/235306)
1. Мастерская живописца или скульптора. — **В**
2. Школа, готовящая художников или актёров. Цирковая студия. — **В**
3. Название некоторых театральных коллективов молодых актёров. Театр-студия. — **В**
4. Предприятие по производству кино- или телефильмов, киностудия или телестудия. — **НА**
5. Специальное помещение, откуда производятся радио- или телевизионные передачи. Работать в студии. — **В**

Подбираем так называемые «парные» предлоги (**НА — С; В — ИЗ**) и делаем вывод:
в четвертом случае — уволить **со**; в остальных — уволить **из**.

[Предлоги ИЗ и С](http://textis.ru/predlogi-kogda-s-a-kogda-iz/)

Answer (score 2):

Я рекомендую говорить "**уволен со студии**". 
Аргументация ниже.

Оба варианта "уволен из" и "уволен с(со)" общеупотребимы и допустимы. В книгах (в том числе в разнообразных законодательных документах) они встречаются довольно часто.

Каким правилом руководствоваться при выборе предлога? В русском языке предлогам **НА** и **В** соответствуют предлоги **С** и **ИЗ**. И если человек работал (или был принят на работу) **НА** что-то, то увольняется он **С** того же, а если **В** — тогда **ИЗ**.

Можете попробовать для сравнения:
работал на стройке — уволен со стройки;
работал на заводе — уволен с завода;
работал в органах — уволен из органов;
работал в университете — уволен из университета, и т.д.

В большинстве случаев альтернатива режет слух. В редких случаях, правда, другой вариант тоже приживается в разговорной речи вместе с правильным.

В Вашем случае возможны, казалось бы, оба варианта, поскольку работать можно и в студии, и на студии. Но я почему-то смог найти поиском только примеры "уволен со студии". Например, Д.Д. Шостакович в "Письмах к другу" писал:

> Трауберг (сопостановщик кинотрилогии о Максиме), обвиненный в
>   «космополитизме», был **уволен со студии** «Ленфильм»...

Я рекомендую Вам использовать в данном случае этот вариант, как более распространённый.

Comment: Всё хорошо, но встречаются и варианты "работает в [студии]" + название. "Работает в "Мельнице" "Работет в HBO", по правилам эллипсиса в русском в продолжение этих фраз возможно и "из".

Comment: @Manjusri Вы не дочитали мой ответ до конца :) Это обсуждалось в третьем абзаце снизу. Насчёт эллписиса: я понял так, что интересовал вопрос словоупотребления без него.

Answer (score 1):

"Уволен со студии" мне кажется просторечным вариантом.

"Уволен из студии" звучит странно.

Проверяем по корпусу.

**"уволен(а/ы/о) со"** - вопреки ожиданиям, не встречается ни одного случая "уволен со скандалом", зато есть 12 случаев "уволен со службы / с поста". Корпусные примеры - это начало ХХ века, дореволюционный "серебряный" стиль; пять случаев "уволены со службы / постов / должностей" в тот же период и в неоимперские времена (50-е ХХ века);

**"уволен(а/ы/о) из":**

> Кто ж, будучи уволен из нашей службы, пожелает отъехать в другие
>   европейские государства, таким давать нашей Иностранной коллегии
>   надлежащие паспорты беспрепятственно... [Петр III]. Манифест о
>   даровании вольности и свободы всему российскому дворянству (1762)],всего 88 случаев;

какая-то монахиня

> была "уволена из обители" [Н. С. Лесков. Епархиальный суд (1880)],
>   всего случаев 12;
>
> ― Какого вы звания? ― Мы уволены из казенной палаты. ― Я бы просил вас
>   поменьше писать. [Э. И. Стогов. Записки (1870-1880)], всего 21 случай;
>
> Как ни странно, его тело так и не было уволено из Института генетики,
>   поскольку в положенные сроки сдавало годовые отчеты и что-то говорило
>   на ученых советах. [Наль Подольский. Книга Легиона // «Октябрь»,
>   2001], один случай.

Таким образом, допустимы оба варианта, но форма "уволен из" - более продуктивная и распространенная, а значит, более употребимая.